How would the police find Cooper at the concert in Trap?
What are the police looking for that would enable them to identify the Butcher as he leaves the concert? It seems like whatever it is, Cooper could easily just discard it before leaving the stadium.

They have visual profiles on various men who were seen in the area where the Butcher's victims were found. They're questioning, and evidently planning to arrest, anyone who matches one of those profiles.

Surveillance footage from area where victims’ bodies were found, recorded men of various builds;  A redheaded male, two African-American males above average height, a male with white hair in his 60s, a white male in his 30s with a tattoo of a rabbit or animal on his right arm, a white male with a scar on his lower jaw.

He can't discard his wrist tattoo, but he does make an effort to cover it later in the film.

Sucks to be a redhead at this concert.

It seems a rather expensive way to do this as opposed to tracking down the tickets, although there’s the later reveal that Cooper’s wife was the one who left the receipt at the house which again, feels like a rather convoluted way to try to get him arrested, but then I guess I shouldn’t expect too much logic from a Shyamalan film.
